# Javascript execute a function of the number of indexes in two arrays are equal?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to execute a function when two arrays have an equal length that is greater than zero.

My program assigns the class of 'letter' to each list item in the phrase div. If a button press matches a letter in that div, that letter gets assigned the class 'show' which reveals it to the user.

I don't understand why my win condition isn't being met. Is there something wrong with the way I'm comparing the length of the two indexes?

I've included my codePen here: https://codepen.io/Azo3307/pen/vPjwxr

My checkWin() function is on line 100, and then it is called on line 143 after each button press is triggered.

```
    // Check win condition

function checkWin() {
    let showClass = document.getElementsByClassName('show');
    let lettersClass = document.getElementsByClassName('letters');
    if (showClass.length == lettersClass.length && showClass.length > 0 && lettersClass.length > 0) {
        console.log('you win');
        addElement('win', `You Win!`, `"${phraseArray}" is correct! `);
    } else if (missed == 5) {
        console.log('you lose');
        addElement('lose', 'Game Over!', 'Better luck next time!');
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You look for elements with class "letters" but the elements are created with class "letter" (no "s").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're asking for let `document.getElementsByClassName('letters')` instead of `letter`:

```
<li class="letter show">t</li>
```

Second point, if `showClass.length == lettersClass.length` and `showClass.length > 0`, you don't need to test `lettersClass.length > 0` ;)

```
function checkWin() {
    let showClass = document.getElementsByClassName('show');
    let lettersClass = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
    if (showClass.length == lettersClass.length && showClass.length > 0) {
        console.log('you win');
        addElement('win', `You Win!`, `"${phraseArray}" is correct! `);
    } else if (missed == 5) {
        console.log('you lose');
        addElement('lose', 'Game Over!', 'Better luck next time!');
    }
}
```

Last one, it's easy to know the text before trying anything just by selecting all the block ;) You should `display:none` instead of put it transparent.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. Thank you. I thought my comparrison wasn't working. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Line 102:

```
let lettersClass = document.getElementsByClassName('letters');
```

rename to

```
let lettersClass = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
```

Looks like just small typo. Btw code looks great, thumbs up.

Comment: Thank you so much. I cannot believe I missed something so stupid. Thank you for taking the time to look over my code and find the error. Much appreciated.